# What is your favourite javascript lightbox implementation?

Tags: website-features

There are so many implementations of the lightbox, which is your favourite to use for your custom site? (javascript based)

I generally use [Lightbox2](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you mean by lightbox (pure JS implementation, for integration on custom sites, plugin to existing CMS or Blog, what?).  One-sentence questions are borderline down-vote for me.

Comment: Good point, clarified a little, was just looking at general custom site implementations

Comment: I'm not sure that clarification helped! By "custom" do you mean "hand-coded" as opposed to "off-the-shelf product"? Most lightboxes I've used (including the one in my example) are JS implementations, so it doesn't really matter whether the site runs on wordpress or compiled C code.

Answer (score 3):

[Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) is a very nice one I recently discovered. It handles youtube videos particularly well.

Answer (score 1):

I like Nick Stakenburg's [Lightview](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/), even though it's based on prototype and it requires a lot of frameworks. From my testing, it behaves identical in all the browsers.

Comment: +1 I've been looking for a good prototype based light box

Comment: This one is solid. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I like [PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/). It's lightweight, easy to use, built on jQuery, can open anything you could need.

Answer (score 0):

[ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) is pretty good, though I have had a problem with smaller images and/or longer title captions (it does not stretch the bounding box if the text wraps).

Answer (score 0):

The classic one is [ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/). It is no longer maintained but is great if you want a nice, simple lightbox with no fuss.

Answer (score 0):

I like [LyteBox](http://www.dolem.com/lytebox/) for it's small size. Although I had to modifiy it to support "close on click" feature.

Answer (score 0):

[Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) is pretty sweet. Not only it can generate the usual image galeries, it also can generate lightboxed out of videos, flash or even html (good for contextual help).
It also has many ways of handling large images (crop, pan, zoom, etc), and you can close the box with esc.
Standalone, but compatible with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a flexible lightbox that can handle any type of media, check out [mediaboxAdvanced](http://iaian7.com/webcode/mediaboxAdvanced) for [MooTools](http://mootools.net/).

It supports:

- Images
- Twitter
- Social Video
- Flash media
- Quicktime
- Inline
- HTML